# Keyword for referencing the current instance : TclOO

Tags: tcl

I would like to know if this `keyword` exists in `oo::class` to qualify the members of the class ? Instead of the `constructor` parameters. like the keyword [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) in `C#`

```
public class Point2D
{
    private double X;
    private double Y;

    public Point2D(double x, double y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't comprehend your question. Please give us a snippet of code that requires this command. Is [`self`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/self.htm) what you're looking for?

Comment: @glennjackman I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `variable` command to declare an "instance variable". Translating that class to TclOO, I'd write

```
oo::class create Point2D {
    variable X
    variable Y

    constructor {x y} {
        set X $x
        set Y $y
    }
}
```

Now, you can use instance variables `$X` and `$Y` in your methods with no further syntax or commands:

```
oo::define Point2D {
    # the distance from point (0, 0) to self
    method distance {} {
        return [expr {hypot($X, $Y)}]
    }
}
```

Now:

```
% set p [Point2D new 6 8]
% $p distance
10.0
```

Futher reading:

- [Object Oriented Programming in Tcl](https://www.magicsplat.com/articles/oo.html)

Answer (score 2):

You've got several options. My favourite is to use the `variable` *declaration* in the class to make the variables just appear in the methods (including constructor and destructor). This also allows for some clever compilation tricks behind the scenes which make this actually rather fast too (especially once you start getting a lot of methods):

```
oo::class create Point2D {
    variable X Y

    constructor {x y} {
        set X $x
        set Y $y
    }
}
```

You have other options too.

This uses the `variable` standard non-exported method (it's provided by `oo::object`), which is analogous to using `global` except for instance variables.

```
oo::class create Point2D {
    constructor {x y} {
        my variable X Y; # Needed in each method
        set X $x
        set Y $y
    }
}
```

The standard `variable` command can do the job too; the variables are always just standard variables in the current namespace (except for private variables in 8.7 onwards; those use name mangling that `variable` can't handle).

```
oo::class create Point2D {
    constructor {x y} {
        variable X
        variable Y
        set X $x
        set Y $y
        # The above four lines could have been the single line:
        #    variable X $x Y $y
        # but that's *very* specific to what this constructor is doing.
    }
}
```

The other option is the `varname` non-exported method (again of `oo::class`), which returns the fully-qualified name of an instance variable. This is not the best option here though it will serve… but is extremely useful for using with `vwait`, Tk widgets, etc.

```
oo::class create Point2D {
    constructor {x y} {
        set [my varname X] $x
        set [my varname Y] $y
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this last option is the slowest because it works with qualified names rather than being able to be more efficient. (I guess you can find other mechanisms too by contorting things, but these are the key ones that I'd recommend.)

Comment: The differences in highlighting between the snippets are bizarre.